# Converting Unsymmetric Vector-List into Matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

How is it possible to convert a list object (*with different length*) into a matrix object in an *efficient* way! Following example clarify the afore-mentioned goal:

imagine you have a list object of structure:

```
l <- list(c(1,2), c(5,7,3,11))
print(l)

# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2

# [[2]]
# [1]  5  7  3 11
```

The aim is to get a matrix or data.frame in form of:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2   NA   NA
[2,]    5    7    3   11
```

It's very easy to tackle the problem with for-loop. Do you have any idea, how is it possible to make this kind of transformation easily? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try

```
t(sapply(l, `length<-`, max(sapply(l, length))))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    2   NA   NA
#[2,]    5    7    3   11
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it:

```
n <- max(sapply(l, length))
t(sapply(l, function(x) if(length(x) < n) c(x, rep(NA, n - length(x))) else x))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2   NA   NA
[2,]    5    7    3   11
```

First we find out the maximum vector length per list element and store it in `n` (which is 4 in this case).

Then, we `sapply` over the list and check if the length of the list element is equal to `n` and if it is, return it, if it's shorter than `n`, return the list element + NA repeated as often as the difference in length. This returns a matrix. We use `t()` on that matrix to transpose it and get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a package, you could also consider `stri_list2matrix` from the "stringi" package:

```
library(stringi)
l <- list(c(1,2), c(5,7,3,11))
stri_list2matrix(l, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "1"  "2"  NA   NA  
# [2,] "5"  "7"  "3"  "11"
```

---

Regarding your question about doing this *efficiently*, @akrun's answer is already pretty efficient, but could be made more efficient by using `vapply` instead of `sapply`. The "stringi" approach is also pretty efficient (and has the benefit of not resorting to cryptic code like `length<-`).

```
funDD <- function() {
  n <- max(sapply(l, length))
  t(sapply(l, function(x) if(length(x) < n) c(x, rep(NA, n - length(x))) else x))
}

funAK <- function() t(sapply(l, `length<-`, max(sapply(l, length))))

funAM <- function() {
  x <- max(vapply(l, length, 1L))
  t(vapply(l, `length<-`, numeric(x), x))
} 

funStringi <- function() stri_list2matrix(l, byrow = TRUE)

## Make a big list to test on
set.seed(1)
l <- lapply(sample(3:10, 1000000, TRUE), function(x) sample(10, x, TRUE))

system.time(out1 <- funDD())
#    user  system elapsed 
#    5.81    0.33    7.02 

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(funAK(), funAM(), funStringi(), times = 10)
# Unit: seconds
#          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#       funAK() 2.350877 2.499963 2.974141 3.123008 3.200545 3.418648    10
#       funAM() 1.154151 1.238235 1.337607 1.287610 1.494964 1.508884    10
#  funStringi() 2.080901 2.168248 2.352030 2.344763 2.462959 2.716910    10
```